# Excel: Getting data from a daily replaced excel file

Tags: excel, onedrive, o365-flow

I have an location in one drive for business where an .xls file is getting daily replaced via flow automation. The data structure, columns is the same. What I want is to create an excel online workbook that would get its data from that daily replaced xls. I tried once but as soon as the source file got replaced and I clicked on Refresh all under data, the operation ended in error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Power Query in that scenario. Depending on the exact circumstances, you could

- Get data from Folder
- Filter the folder to show only files that contain '.xls' in the file name

If after that you still have more than one file, sort them by date modified and keep only the newest one.

Then process that one remaining file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you feedback. I managed to solve it by following this steps

1. In the power query editor window, click Advanced Editor

2. Modified the source parameter value to Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("the sharepoint address of the file").